# How to show a date picker from another page as a popup on button click in current page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

> Page 1

```
<button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm btn-block " >Schedule order</button>
```

> Page 2

```
<button class="simplepicker-btn" >Show Picker</button>

> <script>
>     let simplepicker = new SimplePicker({
>       zIndex: 10
>     });
> 
>     simplepicker.open();
> 
>     const $button = document.querySelector('button');
>     const $eventLog = document.querySelector('.event-log');
>     $button.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
>       simplepicker.open();
>     });
> 
>     // $eventLog.innerHTML += '\n\n';
>     simplepicker.on('submit', (date, readableDate) => {
>       $eventLog.innerHTML += readableDate + '\n';
>     });
> 
>     simplepicker.on('close', (date) => {
>       $eventLog.innerHTML += 'Picker Closed'  + '\n';
>     });   </script>
```

There is a date/time picker in page 2. How can i popup the same when clicking schedule order button in page 1? I've tried changing class name. But nothing is popping up. I'm new to java Script. Thank you

Comment: do you want to show the value of the datetime picker or show the datetime picker element

Comment: To show the date/time picker element

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use an html inject.
Add an empty div block below or above the button, and then give it a unique id like

```
<div id="date-picker"></div>
```

In the Javascript code try this

```
$("#date-picker").load("x.html");
```

Where x.html is the html code of page 2.